# Number of unit preserving ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Recently a few weeks back I was faced with an admission test question. The question goes as follows: 
The number of unit preserving ring homomorphisms from the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_{17}$ is 
a. 0 
b. 2 
c. 4 
d. 8 
I am still unable to approach this question. What do we specifically mean by "unit preserving homomorphism" ? Aren't all homomorphism supposed to preserve unit ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When discussing not-necessarily-unital rings (also known as rngs, since they are rings without identity, that is, without “i”), the natural notion of a ring homomorphism is one which doesn’t necessarily preserve 1, since 1 may not even exist. If you’re used to dealing with unital rings, you can just ignore the clause talking about the map being unit-preserving.

Comment: A unital ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is completely determined by the image of $\sqrt{2}$. Because you know what must happen to $1$, which tells you what happens to every integer. And whatever $\sqrt{2}$ is mapped to, it better have square equal to the image of $2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four.

We need $1\mapsto1$.  And we know $\varphi (\sqrt2) ^2=\varphi (2)=2$.  So does $2$ have a square root (is it a quadratic residue) in $\Bbb Z_{238}$?

So, since $2$ has $2$ square roots $\pmod 7$,  $2 \pmod {17}$ and $1\pmod 2$, we get $2\cdot 2\cdot 1=4$ unital homomorphisms.  (I used [Euler's criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).  For instance, $2^{\frac{7-1}2}\equiv1\pmod 7$.  There are then $1+\genfrac(){}{2}{2}{7}=2$ roots $\pmod7$).

That's there's four distinct choices for $\varphi (\sqrt2) $.  But $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2] =\langle 1,\sqrt2 \rangle $.  So those are the possibilities for $\varphi $.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. Can you give me a more general idea to attack these types of problems ?

Comment: Well,  it all came down to where we could send $\sqrt2 $.  I guess we could  say that this type of argument would generalize to $\Bbb Z[\sqrt p]$, and unital homomorphisms into finite (or probably finitely generated) abelian groups.   The homomorphism is completely determined by where it sends the generators.

Comment: The quadratic residue stuff I encourage you to look over.   It's number theory and group theory (there's lots of overlap).  And it was central here.